# Haskell Stack で依存ライブラリのバージョンを固定したい

Tags: haskell

Stack において、`package.yaml` の `dependencies` に書く依存パッケージのライブラリをマイナーバージョンまで含めてぴったり固定したいです。

たとえば [Shelly](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shelly) の現在の最新バージョンは 1.8.1 ですが、1.8.0 に依存したいとします。このとき `package.yaml` に次のように書いても `stack build` をすると Shelly 1.8.1 に依存しようとしているような表示が出てしまいます。

```
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- shelly == 1.8.0
```

```
>stack build

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for shelly-1.8.1:
    unix needed, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching version
         is 2.7.2.2)
needed due to foo-0.1.0.0 -> shelly-1.8.1

(以下略)
```

(**補足**：Shelly は 1.8.1 においてうっかり unix パッケージに依存してしまい、Windows 環境下でビルドできなくなりました。このため上のエラーが出ています。1.8.0 は unix に依存していないのでこのエラーは出ません)

`shelly == 1.8.0.*` や `shelly >= 1.8.0 && < 1.8.1` と他の書き方を試しても同じ結果となりました。どうすれば特定のバージョンに正確に依存できるのでしょうか？

#### 環境情報

- Windows 10, cmd.exe
- Stack Version 1.9.1, Git revision f9d0042c141660e1d38f797e1d426be4a99b2a3c (6168 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.31.0
- resolver: lts-12.13

#### 詳細な再現手順

```
>stack new foo
>cd foo
>open package.yaml
(dependencies を編集)
>stack build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージで混乱しましたが、shelly-1.8.1 がインストールされようとしている原因は今回私が使っていた resolver (stackage snapshot) に含まれている Shelly のバージョンが 1.8.1 であるからのようです。

バージョンを固定するには、そのバージョンのパッケージを `stack.yaml` の `extra-deps` に追加する必要がありました。今回の場合以下のように書くとちゃんと shelly-1.8.0 がインストールされました。

```
extra-deps:
- shelly-1.8.0
```

また、こうする代わりに resolver を書き換えて shelly-1.8.0 が入っているものにすることでも解決できます。

バージョン制約を守れていないのだからその旨のエラーを出して欲しい気もしますが、とりあえず解決したので自己回答として投稿します。

Comment: stack（と、stackがバージョンを決める際に参照しているStackage）は、原則としてLTS Haskellのバージョンごとに依存するパッケージのバージョンを固定することによって確実にビルドが通ることを保証しているので、仰るとおりstack.yamlを書き換えてextra-depsに追加するか、resolver:の箇所を書き換えて別のバージョンのLTS Haskellを指定するしかありません。

Comment: @YujiYamamoto さん、ありがとうございます。やはりそうですよね。resolver を書き換える方法も回答に追加しておきました。